# Delphi - DB Refresh alternative

Tags: database, delphi, firebird

I am using Delphi with Firebird DB in a software that display many calculations and according to requirement I need to store and display the total whenever other dependent tables gets updated.

I am currently using the refresh method for several TIBTable components to display the result of these calculations to the user. considering this a multi user app and the fact that refresh make posting slow, is there any alternative to refresh or more optimized way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a multi-user application, where clients need to receive notifications, one option is to use **[Firebird events](http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=psql&topic=102)** to send a 'broadcast' message for every data change (SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE).

Clients can 'register' (listen) for a specific message type, and whenever the Firebird server sends a message with this type, they will receive it, and run client application code, which in your case would refresh a user interface object to display the total.

While this can be a sufficient solution in many simple use cases, there are also some restrictions. I recently blogged about this topic here:

- [Firebird Database Events and Message-oriented Middleware](http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/firebird-database-events-and-message-oriented-middleware/)

(I am author of middleware libraries for Delphi and Free Pascal)

Answer (score 1):

There's really no way around refreshing to get new data.  But if you were using [IBObjects](http://www.ibobjects.com/) for your database access, you could use the `TIBOTable.InvalidateBookmark` method to have it only refresh specific rows.  This is a lot faster than calling `Refresh`, which refreshes the entire dataset.

Looking at [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/IBTable.TIBTable), it doesn't appear that TIBTable has anything comparable, unfortunately.